# Adding an element to variant list/array in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add an item to list.

```
vList as variant
vList = RefData.NameList
iCount = UBound(vList)
If RefData.Mode = "On" Then
  vList.Add("-2")
```

RefData is a sheet with reference data.My name list returns values 3 and 9.If mode is "on" I want it to return 3,9 and -2.

It is throwing object error.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

An array is not an object, and therefore doesn't have any properties or methods you can call. You need to resize the array and then add the item like this

```
Dim counter as long
vList as variant
vList = RefData.NameList
iCount = UBound(vList)
If RefData.Mode = "On" Then
  vlist = Application.transpose(vlist)
  counter = ubound(vList)
  redim preserve vlist(1 to counter +1)
  vlist(counter + 1) = -2
  vlist = Application.transpose(vlist)
End If
```

The transposing is necessary because assigning a range to a Variant always creates a 2D array and you can only resize the last element of an array if you use Preserve to maintain its contents.