# Adding an element to the end of an array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, element

Q&A:
How can one add an element to a the end of a (dynamic) array in VBA?

This same question was for a list in stead of an array:
[Adding an element to variant list/array in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622231/adding-an-element-to-variant-list-array-in-vba)
This same question was about redimensioning arrays with 2 dimensions:
[ReDiming an array in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855289/rediming-an-array-in-vba)
This same question did not ask for the general simple case:  https://superuser.com/questions/808798/adding-an-element-to-the-end-of-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a short VBA code to:

1. Create a dynamic array.
2. Redimension a dynamic array to 3 elements.
3. Fill the newly added element with a value.

   ```
   Sub ChangingArrayLengthShort()
       ' First create array:
       Dim arr() As Variant
       Dim u As Integer
       u = 3

       ReDim arr(1 To u + 1) ' Redimension:
       arr(UBound(arr)) = "SomeValue" ' Fill last element
   End Sub
   ```

This is that code explained:

```
Sub ChangingArrayLength()
    Dim arr() As Variant ' One can only redimension a dynamic array, so:
    'Dim arr(43 to 65) As Variant ' Will yield an error since it is not a dynamic- but a static array.

    Dim NrOfElements As Integer

    NrOfElements = 3
    ReDim arr(1 To NrOfElements) ' Re-dimension array length
    MsgBox (UBound(arr)) ' Show what the last element index is in array arr.

    NrOfElements = NrOfElements + 1 ' Increase the variable that is used to increase the nr of elements in array arr.
    ReDim arr(1 To NrOfElements) ' Re-dimension array length
    MsgBox (UBound(arr)) ' Show what the last element index is in array arr. (And that it increased by 1)

    ' Add value at element to the end of an array:
    arr(UBound(arr)) = "This string is added as last element of array named arr"
End Sub
```

Comment: And of course, you can always get the current upper bound of the array, and add 1 to it, to get that last "empty" item. (No need to guess the new array size, as shown by "NrOfElements = 3" here.

Comment: Thank you! That is indeed a safer way if the array contains an element. However if the array does not contain any dimensions/elements yet, the `UBound(arr)` throws an error in ReDim. So the choice/safety could become situation dependent.

Answer (score 1):

I've already encountered this problem and I solved this way

```
 aArray(Array.IndexOf(aArray, aArray.Last)) 'this same reDim action for resize
```

It also solves the error of the reDim